# Remove string between two strings

Tags: r, regex, string

Suppose I have the following vector:

```
df<- c("@Accessoires A-B [COLL]", "@Accessoires C-D [COLL]",
        "@Components A-D [COLL]","@Components [COLL]", 
        "@Accessoires [COLL]", "@Components H-Z [COLL]")
```

I would like to remove the middle part of the string where A-B or C-D etc. is present. This is an example, in my dataframe there are many possibilities for the letter combinations.

So the desired output would be:

```
"@Accessoires [COLL]" 
"@Accessoires [COLL]" 
"@Components [COLL]"  
"@Components [COLL]"  
"@Accessoires [COLL]" 
"@Components [COLL]"
```

My question is how to achieve this in R without having to define all letter combinations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sub()` and some regular expressions:

```
sub("\\s[A-Z]-[A-Z]\\s", " ", df)
[1] "@Accessoires [COLL]" "@Accessoires [COLL]" "@Components [COLL]"  "@Components [COLL]" 
[5] "@Accessoires [COLL]" "@Components [COLL]"
```

The regular expressions boil down to:

- `\\s`: one space
- `[A-Z]`: any (of the English) upper case letter.

By the way, your `df` is a vector but not a `data.frame`

```
df <- c(
  "@Accessoires A-B [COLL]", "@Accessoires C-D [COLL]","@Components A-D [COLL]",
  "@Components [COLL]", "@Accessoires [COLL]","@Components H-Z [COLL]"
)
is.data.frame(df)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Split on space, get 1st and last element:

```
sapply(strsplit(df, " "), function(i) paste(head(i, 1), tail(i, 1)))

# [1] "@Accessoires [COLL]" "@Accessoires [COLL]" "@Components [COLL]" 
# [4] "@Components [COLL]"  "@Accessoires [COLL]" "@Components [COLL]"
```

Answer (score 0):

`df` is not a `data.frame` but a character vector.
You can remove anything between spaces with `gsub`:

```
gsub(" .* ", " ", df)
[1] "@Accessoires [COLL]" "@Accessoires [COLL]" "@Components [COLL]"  "@Components [COLL]"  "@Accessoires [COLL]" "@Components [COLL]"
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I should have probably mentioned that "@Accesoires" and "@Components" aren't the only combinations, for instance I also have "@Custom dimension A-G [COLL]". In that case removing anything between spaces is not desired, since I would like to keep "@Custom dimension [COLL]".